# Where does the third coil come from in the ideal transformer circuit model pictured in my post?

Tags: transformer

I am having trouble understanding where the coil with current Im flowing through it comes from? All I see in the transformer picture is two coils wrapped around a core. Also, where do the two currents im and I`2 in the picture flow? I would greatly appreciate an explanation.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary current \$i_1\$ is the sum of the magnetizing current \$i_m\$ and the reflected secondary current \$i_2\$. The reflected secondary current is independent of the primary inductance. The magnetizing current depends on the applied primary voltage and the primary inductance.

The model uses Kirchhoff's current law to separate the primary inductance into a "third inductance". The primary side of the ideal transformer has an infinite inductance so that the parallel combination with \$L_m\$ is equal to \$L_m\$.

In this way, the secondary contribution to the primary and the applied voltage contribution can be treated seperately analytically.